# Java Registry key error on windows 8 cmd

Tags: java, cmd, windows-8

I am trying to run the java file on my cmd in windows - 8, but this pops up:

```
Error: Registry key 'Software\JavaSoft\Java Runtime   
Environment'\CurrentVersion'has value '1.8', but '1.7' is required.
Error: could not find java.dll
Error: Could not find Java SE Runtime Environment.
```

Any fixes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds strange. I'd try to uninstall all present Java installations and then reinstall the ones you need.